# Whats the difference between printf("%d","%u","%p",ptr,ptr,ptr) and printf("%d %u %p",ptr,ptr,ptr)?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

When i try printf("%p","%d","%u",ptr,ptr,ptr) i get 00405067 but when i try executing printf("%p %d %u",ptr,ptr,ptr) i get 0061FF28 6422312 6422312 respectively. I understand the latter part but not sure about the former.

```
int main()
{
    int  a = 1;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &a;
    printf("%p","%d","%u",ptr,ptr,ptr);
    return 0;
}
Output: 00405067
________________

int main()
{
    int  a = 1;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &a;
    printf("%p %d %u",ptr,ptr,ptr);
    return 0;
}
Output: 0061FF28 6422312 6422312
```

Comment: Where did the former come from? It's completely wrong.

Comment: The first parameter is the format string which decides what gets printed. One tells printf to print one value the other three.

Comment: i use code blocks and this is what i got :/

Comment: See this link https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-data-types

Comment: They're both undefined behaviour, so technically the same

Comment: @M.M Are you sure the first example has undefined behavior?

Comment: @melpomene Not really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
printf("%p","%d","%u",ptr,ptr,ptr)
```

The format string is just `"%p"`. It prints one pointer, which is the address of `"%d"` (a string literal). The remaining arguments (`"%u", ptr, ptr, ptr`) don't have a corresponding directive in the format string, so they're just ignored.

The call is effectively equivalent to

```
printf("%p", "...");
```

---

Note that `%p` takes a `void *` while `%d` takes an `int` and `%u` takes an `unsigned int`. If you want to print the value of a pointer, the correct solution is to use `%p` and cast the pointer to `(void *)`, as in

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)ptr);
```

To format a pointer as an integer, I believe the only 100% portable solution is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

...
printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(void *)ptr);
```

Comment: "To format a pointer as an integer .... only 100% portable solution" has 2 non-portable aspects.  A rare C99 or later compiler might not have the _optional_ type `(u)intptr_t`.  `(void *)ptr` is well defined when `ptr` is an object pointer, not a function pointer.

Comment: @chux My line of thinking was that the only reason an implementation might not provide this type is if it doesn't support converting pointers to integers at all. Otherwise it wouldn't cost anything to add the `typedef`. Also, if you run into that situation, it'll fail cleanly and early, at compile time.